# Swift String from an enum

Tags: swift, string, enums

I'm trying to get the text here to read the contents of the `privacyNotice` text String which is stored in the `Content` enum extension of `Chat.Message.Incoming`. The below does not compile at this point:

```
private func renderPolicy(
        isEnabled: Bool,
        resource: ChosenResource<Notice>,
        message: Chat.Message.Incoming,
        ) -> Node<NodeId> {
        return Node(
            component: Component.Message(
                ....
                text: message.content.privacyNotice.text,
                ....
        )
    }
```

This is the extension:

```
extension Chat.Message.Incoming {
    public enum Content {
        case text(message: String, style: Style)
        case response(message: String)
        case privacyNotice(text: String, resource: ChosenResource<Notice>)
    }
}
```

In the console when I hit a breakpoint and type `po message.content` I get the below:

```
(lldb) po message.content
▿ Content
  ▿ privacyNotice : 2 elements
    - text : "Privacy"
    ▿ resource : ChosenResource<Notice>
      - generator : (Function)
```

So how do I navigate the error I get when I type out `po message.content.privacyNotice.text`, which is what I would expect to return `Privacy`, and therefore enable me to input this in the `renderPolicy` function:

```
(lldb) po message.content.privacyNotice.text
error: <EXPR>:3:9: error: enum case 'privacyNotice' cannot be used as an instance member
message.content.privacyNotice.text
~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
        Chat.Message.Incoming.Content.

error: <EXPR>:3:31: error: value of type '(String, ChosenResource<Notice>) -> Chat.Message.Incoming.Content' has no member 'text'
message.content.privacyNotice.text
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~
```

TIA

Comment: Would it be possible to just change your `Content` enum to a `struct` or `class`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `renderPolicy` function, `message.content` is simply of type `Content`, it isn't guaranteed to be of case `privacyNotice`, it could also be `text` or `response`, neither of which have `text` associated value.

So in order to access that associated value, you need to make sure that `message.content` is actually of case `privacyNotice` - which you can do using `if case ...`.

```
private func renderPolicy(
    isEnabled: Bool,
    resource: ChosenResource<Notice>,
    message: Chat.Message.Incoming,
    ) -> Node<NodeId> {
    if case .privacyNotice(text: let text, resource: _) = message.content {
        return Node(
        component: Component.Message(
            ....
            text: text,
            ....
        )
    } else {
       // handle the other casese
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `switch` statement and apply [Pattern Matching](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/pattern-matching-in-swift/) to determine your `text` value.

```swift
 private func renderPolicy(
    isEnabled: Bool,
    resource: ChosenResource<Notice>,
    message: Chat.Message.Incoming,
    ) -> Node<NodeId> {

    var nodeText: String

    switch message.content {
    case .response(let message):
        // you can unwrap like this or ...
        nodeText = message
    case let .privacyNotice(text, resource):
        // you can unwrap multiple wrapped values with a single 'let'
        nodeText = text
    case let .text(message, _):
        nodeText = message
    }

    return Node(
        component: Component.Message(
            ...
            text: nodeText,
            ....
    )
}
```

I hope that helps you, feel free to ask further questions.